# MongoDB $ne operator not working on nested object property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to use the $ne (not equal) operator to get a model where the a nested property ( a user model id) is not equal to the current user's id. I am using this for an explore feature to see a list of things, but I don't want to show the user their own things. I build up the query in a series of steps but the user's items are not being filtered out. Here is the step where I try to filter the user's items:

```
  let query;

  injected = {
    ...injected,
    'user._id': { "$ne": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user.id) },
  };
  const reqQuery = { ...req.query, ...injected };

  let queryStr = JSON.stringify(reqQuery);
  query = model.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

the user model looks like this:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'please add a name'],
      trim: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
      unique: true,
      trim: true,
      match: [
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
        /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,
        'Please add a valid email',
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And the model of the thing I am trying to filter:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const ItemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
      required: [true, 'Items must have a user'],
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      trim: true,
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  },
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

Comment: Write a reproduce snippet using mongo shell that inserts some sample data and issues the query, remove everything mongoose related from the question.

Comment: My application is using mongoose so it has to work with mongoose.

Comment: If your question is about mongoose, you shouldn't be asking about MongoDB behavior. And you should provide the MQL that you are having trouble with translating into mongoose code.

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to assist but my code uses mongoDB and mongoose. I can’t separate them in the real world and this is what I would like help with. If you are unable to help that’s perfectly fine :)

Comment: I suggest learning how to separate the components you are working with so that you are not just demanding answers for whatever issue you are facing but are able to utilize existing resources that would assist you with figuring out the solution.